# Problem deploying spring microservice project app to heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku

i have been trying to deploy my spring boot microservice app on heroku but i just move from one issue to another, so many tutorials but with different steps, i dont really know what the problem is presently, it has been deployed successfully, but when i try to view the app, it shows application error... i have added a Procfile and a system.properties file but i still dont know what the issue is...
Here is the log details...

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/java
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 17... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] weddingapp                                                         [pom]
       [INFO] couple                                                             [jar]
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --------------------< com.slinkdigital:weddingapp >---------------------
       [INFO] Building weddingapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                   [1/2]
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ weddingapp ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ weddingapp ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ weddingapp ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_67b8dede/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/slinkdigital/weddingapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/weddingapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ----------------------< com.slinkdigital:couple >-----------------------
       [INFO] Building couple 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                       [2/2]
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ couple ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ couple ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Copying 5 resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 44 source files to /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/target/classes
       [INFO] /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/src/main/java/com/slinkdigital/couple/config/SecurityConfig.java: /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/src/main/java/com/slinkdigital/couple/config/SecurityConfig.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
       [INFO] /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/src/main/java/com/slinkdigital/couple/config/SecurityConfig.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ couple ---
       [INFO] No sources to compile
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Building jar: /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/target/couple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ couple ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/target/couple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/slinkdigital/couple/1.0-SNAPSHOT/couple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_67b8dede/Couple/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/slinkdigital/couple/1.0-SNAPSHOT/couple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Reactor Summary for weddingapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] weddingapp ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.961 s]
       [INFO] couple ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.408 s]
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  5.788 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-14T06:49:15Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 66.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v24
       https://weddingappl.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
This app is using the Heroku-20 stack, however a newer stack is available.
To upgrade to Heroku-22, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack
```

This is my Procfile
web: java -Dspring.profiles.active=default -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar

This is my system.properties file
java.runtime.version=17

And this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.slinkdigital</groupId>
    <artifactId>weddingapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>weddingapp</name>
    <url>https://www.slink.com.ng</url>
    <description>Wedding Application Project (Parent)</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.dependencies.version>2.7.0</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
        <spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>2.7.0</spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.dependencies.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>Couple</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

This is the pom.xml for couple module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.slinkdigital</groupId>
        <artifactId>weddingapp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>couple</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <name>couple</name>
</project>
```

This is my app.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

I have added a snapshot of the error am facing...
[image]

[image]
Please i will appreciate the assistance... i have added heroku postgres addon

Comment: What do you mean by Application Error? Please provide details or some screenshots regarding the error you are getting. I can only see the INFO logs in your deployment build which suggests that there is no issue with the heroku deployment. Maybe I can get some idea from the error?

Comment: @ShantanuVora thanks for the response, i have added some snapshots of the error